# How to add both images and text in a Text Area?

Tags: android

I am writing an application to save some text data along with images embedded inside the text on my server.My question is how to add both image and text to a text area in Android application?remember user will add the image and write text in the text area so we can not hard code it.

Comment: How will they add the image into the Text Area?

Comment: Can you describe how your user will interact with your app? Perhaps provide mockups of what you want the screen to look like.

Comment: If they upload image separately and write text, You should have a Layout with ImageView and EditText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite a lot of work when it's an EditText and user can type there but it will surely work. Read about [ImageSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ImageSpan.html) - it will do what you want to do. You simply have to create a Spannable with:

```
Spannable span = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(text);
```

later set ImageSpan with:

```
span.setSpan(new ImageSpan(drawable), start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

and set this span for your EditText

```
editText.setText(span);
```

I think you should add your images as `<heart> <smile> <sad>` etc. And make a short method that will find such strings, create appropriate spans and set this span in the EditText.

Answer (score 0):

You can either set the image as the background or you can use a relative layout and put a textview over top of the imageview.

```
<EditText
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/your_pic"
  android:hint="@string/your_hint_text" />
```

or

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/your_pic" />
    <EditText
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:hint="@string/your_hint_text" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Based on Rani's feedback I switched to EditText

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a Layout for that.

If you want to set the image as background you could use `FrameLayout`

Answer (score 0):

I second Cory Roy's answer with a slight modification. SInce you said the user can enter text. Instead of `TextView` use `EditText`.

```
<RelativeLayout 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/your_pic" />
    <EditText
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/your_text"
      android:hint=@"string/your_hint_text" />
</RelativeLayout>
```